$f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, $f(x)\geq 0$, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, then $f$ is constant

$f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$, $f(x)\geq 0$, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, then $f$ is constant

I know many topics considering the following problem without $f\geq 0$. It or its method does not fit it. Can you help?
$f'(x)+f(x)=f(x+1)\geq 0$, $e^xf(x)$ is increasing....then?

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that
$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad : \quad f(x) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad f'(x) = f(x+1) - f(x). $$
Now set $g(x) =e^x f(x)$. Then it is easy to verify that $g \geq 0$ and
$$ g'(x) = e^{-1} g(x+1), \quad \text{i.e.,} \quad g(x) = e g'(x-1).  $$
From this, we know that $g$ is absolutely monotone on $\mathbb{R}$. So by the Bernstein's theorem, there exists a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0, \infty)$ such that
$$ g(x) = \int_{[0, \infty)} e^{xt} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}t), \quad \forall x \leq 0. $$
Now let $x$ be arbitrary, and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be any positive integer such that $x \leq n$. Then
\begin{align*}
g(x)
&= e^n g^{(n)}(x - n) \\
&= e^n \int_{[0, \infty)} t^n e^{(x-n)t} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}t) \\
&= \int_{[0, \infty)} e^{xt} (t e^{1-t})^n \, \mu(\mathrm{d}t).
\end{align*}
However, for $t \geq 0$, we have $t e^{1-t} \leq 1$ with the equality if and only if $t = 1$. So, if
$$ h_{n}(t) = e^{xt} (t e^{1-t})^n $$
denotes the the integrand, then we observe:

$h_{n}(t)$ is non-negative and monotone decreasing in $n$,
$h_{n}(t)$ is $\mu$-integrable for any sufficiently large $n$, and
$h_{n}(t)$ converges pointwise to $e^x \mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(t)$ as $n \to \infty$.

So by letting $n \to \infty$, the dominated convergence theorem shows that
\begin{align*}
g(x)
&= \int_{[0, \infty)} e^{xt} \mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(t) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}t)
= C e^x
\end{align*}
for $C = \mu(\{1\})$. Therefore $f(x) = e^{-x}g(x) = C$ is constant.

Addendum - Some Ideas for Another Proof. Let $f$ solve the functional equation. We can prove that, for the compensated Poisson process $X_t = N_t - t$, where $N_t$ is the Poisson process with unit rate, we have
$$ f(a) = \mathbf{E}[f(a+X_t)]. $$
In other words, $f$ is $X$-harmonic, and $f(a+X_t)$ is a martingale.

This has to do with the fact that $e^D - 1$ is the infinitesimal generator of $N_t$, where $D = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Note that the functional equation reads as $e^D f = (1 + D) f$. Now, this yields yet another formal identity $f = e^{t(e^D - 1)} e^{-tD} f$, which translates to the above identity.


I am curious whether we can utilize this fact to give yet another proof that $f$ is constant.

May be a shorter way in the excellent solution of Sangchul Lee. $g'(x)=e^{-1}g(x+1)$ implies that the following two positive measures $t\mu(t)$ and $e^{t-1}\mu(dt)$ coincide, that is $t=e^{t-1}$ holds $\mu$ almost everywhere, that is $\mu=\delta_1.$

@LetacGérard, That's a great observation! Thank you for the simplification :)

Beautiful solution! (+)

Partial solution: As you say, the function $e^xf(x)$ is incrreasing,
so $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^xf(x)=A<\infty\quad \text{or}\quad \infty.$$
If $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^xf(x)=A$, then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=0.$$
Hence, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]=0,$$
then by the result in the post $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(x)$: prove $f(x)$ linear function, we get that $f(x)=ax+b$. Combining $f(x)\to0$, we know that $a=b=0,f(x)\equiv0.$
If $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^xf(x)=\infty$, I have no idea now! Hope someone can give a complete solution!

@
Ryszard Szwarc
Yes, thank you for your comment!
